# Cubic graph with a bridge

Tags: graph-theory

Please, could you let me know how to prove:
The edge-chromatic number of a cubic graph with a bridge is 4.

My idea:

The bridge will divide graph G into two parts $C_{1}$, $C_{2}$.
Then, we consider $C_{1}$, every vertex of $C_{1}$ except the vertex $a_{1}$ which is incident to bridge, has degree 3.

$deg(a_{1})=2$.

So, the number of vertex of $C_{1}$ is an odd number.

At that step, I don't know how to continue or maybe, that is a wrong way.

Comment: Please, give a reference for the reader to see definitions of "cubic graph" and "bridge".

Comment: Cubic graph is the 3-regular graph.

Comment: Do you know Vizing's theorem?

Comment: Yes, I have solved it. I prove it by using induction on the edges.